# What To Do If You Made The Same Bracha Twice?

Tags: halacha

What should one do if he made the same bracha twice.
An Example:
say someone makes a shehakol on some corn chips or something and then 5 mintues later he made another shehakol on a coffee.
is this wrong?
and what should he do to rectify for future?

Answer (score 4):

in the case you brought up it seems that when he made a bracha on the corn chips he didn't have in mind or see the coffee in which case he would anyway need to make another bracha. however were he to have had the coffee in mind or it was in front of him and he did not divert his mind from it until he made the second bracha' the second bracha is deemed a bracha she'eina tzricha and he should say ברוך שם כבוד מלכותו לעולם ועד

Comment: Welcome to MY! When you get a chance, would you please [edit] your answer to include some sources?

Comment: Adding some sources will improve this answer.